# SQL Server: String Manipulation, Unpivoting

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a column called `body`, which contains body content for our CMS.  The data looks like:

> ...{cloak:id=1.1.1}...{cloak}...{cloak:id=1.1.2}...{cloak}...{cloak:id=1.1.3}...{cloak}...

A moderately tweaked for readability example:

```
## h5. A formal process for approving and testing all external network connections and changes to the firewall and router configurations? 
{toggle-cloak:id=1.1.1}{tree-plus-icon} *Compliance:* {color:red}{*}Partial{*}{color} (?) 
{cloak:id=1.1.1} || Date: | 2010-03-15 || || Owner: | Brian || || Researched by: | || || Narrative: | Jira tickets are normally used to approve and track network changes\\ || || Artifacts: | Jira.bccampus.ca\\ || || Recommendation: | Need to update policy that no Jira = no change\\ || || Proposed Remedy(ies): | || || Approved Remedy(ies): | || || Date: | || || Reviewed by: | || || Remarks/comments: | || 
{cloak}## h5. Current network diagrams with all connections to cardholder data, including any wireless networks? 
{toggle-cloak:id=1.1.2}{tree-plus-icon} *Compliance:* {color:red}{*}TBD{*}{color} (?) 
{cloak:id=1.1.2}
```

I'd like to get the cloak values out in the following format:

```
 requirement_num
 -----------------
 1.1.1
 1.1.2
 1.1.3
```

I'm looking at using UNIONs - does anyone have a better recommendation?

Forgot to mention:

- I can't use regex, because CLR isn't enabled on the database.
- The numbers aren't sequencial.  The current record jumps from 1.1.6 to 1.2.1
- I can guarantee that there will be a pair for each requirement number - `{toggle-cloak:id=x.y.z}` and `{cloak:id=x.y.z}`.  I'm interested in what is between the `{cloak:id=x.y.z}` and `{cloak}` tags.

Comment: Is that all... one long string?  In one column/row?  *(Bah to your stealth edits)*

Comment: UNIONs ? Not sure I follow you there.

Comment: @Remus: Handling 1.1.1 related in first query, UNION ALL to handling 1.1.2 in second, etc.

Comment: Search all possible values in each row? Unless you have FT index and a custom stemmer to isolate `{cloak:id=x.y.z}` into a token will be very slow on large sets, obviously.

Comment: is the text always `{cloak:id=^^^^^}` where the data you want is `^^^^^`?

Comment: Hey OMG Ponies, Can you show us what exactly is the string. What is between the .....

Comment: @KM: I can't guarantee that it will always be five characters long.

Comment: And what of {toggle-cloak:id=1.1.1} vs {cloak:id=1.1.1}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably use a function for this. Something like:

```
create function [dbo].[getCloaks]
(
@String     varchar(8000)
)
returns @tbl table (s varchar(1000))
as
begin
declare @i int, @j int, @k int
    select  @i = 1
    while charindex('{cloak:id=', @String, @i) > 0
    begin
        select @j = charindex('{cloak:id=', @String, @i)
        select @k = charindex('}', @String, @j)
        insert  @tbl select substring(@String, @j + 10, @k - @j - 10)
        select  @i = @k + 1
    end
    return
end
```

Comment: +1: Well done, passes my tests.  Do you think you could do it in a CTE?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive CTE version that will hopefully be a little faster than an iterative UDF:

```
DECLARE @Data nvarchar(1000)

SET @Data = N'...{cloak:id=1.1.1}...{cloak}...{cloak:id=1.1.2}...{cloak}...' +
            N'{cloak:id=1.1.3}...{cloak}...'

;WITH Cloak_CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        CAST(NULL AS nvarchar(50)) AS requirement_num,
        CHARINDEX('{cloak:id=', @Data) AS start_index,
        CHARINDEX('}', @Data, CHARINDEX('{cloak:id=', @Data)) AS end_index

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        CAST(SUBSTRING(@Data, start_index + 10,
            end_index - start_index - 10) AS nvarchar(50)),
        CHARINDEX('{cloak:id=', @Data, end_index + 1),
        CHARINDEX('}', @Data, CHARINDEX('{cloak:id=', @Data, end_index + 1))
    FROM Cloak_CTE
    WHERE start_index > 0
)
SELECT requirement_num
FROM Cloak_CTE
WHERE requirement_num IS NOT NULL
```

Should be relatively straightforward to adjust for multiple rows or different patterns, or put this into an inline UDF.

Comment: Sorry, left out a few curly brackets on the first take - when I went to put in my answer I saw your edit with the `toggle-cloak:id` tokens and realized I needed the opening bracket, and a few things got lost in translation.  I tested the updated SQL against your real example and it works now.